# FATAL: Invalid ID Jenkins IIS

Tags: git, iis, jenkins

I'm trying to set up Jenkins to pull and build a project from bitbucket.

I'm using this on IIS 8.5 Server 2012 r2. I've set up the Git and Bitbucket plugins.

I've set up a project with the following:

```
Branch Specifier (blank for 'any'): "origin/master"
```

I'm not sure if this is part of the issue, but I only have that one branch in my repo.

When running the build I'm getting the following error, I can't find any information as to what the ID is that's invalid, can anyone point me in the right direction?

It looks like it's fetching the hash from the last commit, and then saying invalid ID, I'm not sure if that's the hash ID or if it's some kind of environmental ID as it's referencing the build directory (which does exist and has the correct permissions) when it fails

Error log:

```
Started by user Stu
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Fenix
 > C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe config remote.origin.url https://user@bitbucket.org/project/project-fenix.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://user@bitbucket.org/project/project-fenix.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe fetch --tags https://user@bitbucket.org/project/project-fenix.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
FATAL: Invalid id: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Fenix>
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.InvalidObjectIdException: Invalid id: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Fenix>
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectId.fromString(ObjectId.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.revParse(CliGitAPIImpl.java:689)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.revParse(GitAPI.java:316)
    at hudson.plugins.git.util.DefaultBuildChooser.getHeadRevision(DefaultBuildChooser.java:130)
    at hudson.plugins.git.util.DefaultBuildChooser.getCandidateRevisions(DefaultBuildChooser.java:112)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:992)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1095)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1278)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I've seen a lot of places reference using `git.cmd` instead of the `.exe`, but no cmd file exists in my Git directory. If I use any of the `.exe` files it times out and cannot make a connection, so I'm using `C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe` and it is at least connecting.

The Git verion is Git for Windows v2.10.2

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated as I can't find anything online about this specific error.

Answer (score 6):

Please **don't** use git-cmd.exe as the git implementation for Jenkins.  Use git.exe from the bin directory of the git installation, or from the cmd directory of the git instalaltion.  It works better, is tested, and is the supported way.

As far as I can tell, git-cmd.exe is the program bundled with git which is used to start a Windows command processor that includes git in the path.  I'm impressed that it runs any git commands, but it seems to do so.  It doesn't run all the git commands, and provides novel and interesting error messages instead.

Refer to [JENKINS-45212](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45212) for an example of a use case where that form of the git program behaves incorrectly, while `git.exe` behaves as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The first test to try is to get rid of:

- any space
- any special characters (like `(x86)`)

Since you have downloaded a portable version of Git, you can uncompress that archive in `C:\prgs\gits\git2.10.2` for instance.

And you can setup your Jenkins workspace to a simpler PATH.

Then check if the issue persists.

---

From [your Jenkins job logs](http://pastebin.com/bBYfvZA4):

```
> C:\ick\git\git-cmd.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
FATAL: Invalid id: C:\ick\jenkins\workspace\fenix>
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.InvalidObjectIdException: Invalid id: C:\ick\jenkins\workspace\fenix>
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectId.fromString(ObjectId.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.revParse(CliGitAPIImpl.java:689)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.revParse(GitAPI.java:316)
    at hudson.plugins.git.util.DefaultBuildChooser.getHeadRevision(DefaultBuildChooser.java:130)
    at hudson.plugins.git.util.DefaultBuildChooser.getCandidateRevisions(DefaultBuildChooser.java:112)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:992)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1095)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
```

It looks like [issue 34886](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34886). In your case, maybe the remote BitBucket repo does not have a branch named "master", making the dereferencing of  "`refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}`" impossible.

Comment: Hi @VonC, thanks for the suggestion, I've moved Git and also jenkins to C:/ick/, I'm getting the same error: pastebin.com/bBYfvZA4. I can't think what the id could be that's invalid? Could it be you have to setup ssh keys, that username and password authentication is not enough?

Comment: Hi @VonC, thanks a lot, I believe it does here's a few console outputs from the same repo: http://pastebin.com/U2iQh2Yj. I had the "Branch Specifier" in the Jenkins project setup as `*/master`, which seems to be calling `refs/remotes/origin/master` in the build

Comment: @Stu I just got the same problem: Jenkins always checkout origin/master, not master. You need to make sure (with a `git branch -avv` in your Jenkins workspace) that the remote repo fetched by Jenkins does include a remote branch origin/master.