# Jenkins build Error local repository Windows Server 2016

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, windows-server-2016

I am new to Jenkins and want to build a CI-environment. I have a local repository with files to get built by Ant.

when I start the build manually I get this errors:

Building in workspace C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\workspace\ToolchainXQT

> C:\Git\git-cmd.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
>   Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
>   C:\Git\git-cmd.exe config remote.origin.url file:///C:/HelloWorld # timeout=10
>   Fetching upstream changes from file:///C:/HelloWorld
>   C:\Git\git-cmd.exe --version # timeout=10
>   C:\Git\git-cmd.exe fetch --tags file:///C:/HelloWorld +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>   C:\Git\git-cmd.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
>   FATAL: Invalid id: C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\workspace\ToolchainXQT>
>   org.eclipse.jgit.errors.InvalidObjectIdException: Invalid id: C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\workspace\ToolchainXQT>
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectId.fromString(ObjectId.java:232)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.revParse(CliGitAPIImpl.java:689)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.revParse(GitAPI.java:316)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.util.DefaultBuildChooser.getHeadRevision(DefaultBuildChooser.java:130)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.util.DefaultBuildChooser.getCandidateRevisions(DefaultBuildChooser.java:112)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:992)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1095)
>       at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1278)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
>       at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
>       at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
>   Finished: FAILURE

When I leave the branch specifier blank, then I get this:

Building in workspace C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\workspace\ToolchainXQT

> C:\Git\git-cmd.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
>   Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
>   C:\Git\git-cmd.exe config remote.origin.url file:///C:/HelloWorld # timeout=10
>   Fetching upstream changes from file:///C:/HelloWorld
>   C:\Git\git-cmd.exe --version # timeout=10
>   C:\Git\git-cmd.exe fetch --tags file:///C:/HelloWorld +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>   Seen 0 remote branches
>   ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
>   Finished: FAILURE

I hope someone can help me, explain me this messages or tell me what you need to know to help me.

Thanks in advice,
Max

Comment: can you try to do a clone in local  : git clone C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\workspace\ToolchainXQT

Comment: max@ToolchainXQT MINGW64 /c/ProgramData/Jenkins/workspace/ToolchainXQT (master)

$ git clone C:/HelloWorld
Cloning into 'HelloWorld'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
done.

That's the output from git-bash opnened in C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\workspace\ToolchainXQT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you have a empty repository you must create a available git repository so your repo directory you do

## git init

you add your files
do

## git add .

## git commit -m "inital git repo"

in first time try to clone your repo from other consol by git clone if it works go a head to Jenkins and enjoy

Answer (score 1):

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44847857/3043709 for a description why you should use git.exe from the cmd or the bin directory, instead of git-cmd.exe.